# In-App purchases with thumbnail previews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, thumbnails

I am beginning looking into adding in-app purchasing to my iPad app (Objective-C, not swift) with the files being hosted by Apple, but I don't see anything that says it can do what I want it to do.

I do not see how to specify a customer-viewable thumbnail, just the ones for apple staff to see for review.

My app is a graphics program, and the in-app purchases are clipart, so the user will need to be able to see the thumbnail to know if they want to buy it. I am not including the files in the app bundle, because that would be huge, and I plan on constantly adding more clipart.

At this point the only thing I can think of is putting thumbnails on a web server and fetching ones that match a particular product ID, but I would think/hope that there is a simpler solution.

(also, if anyone can point me to a nice newish tutorial that is better than the Apple documentation, that would help too!)

EDIT:
Do I get some kind of award for asking a question nobody can seem to answer?
A free iPad maybe? Huh huh? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't provide metadata for hosted downloads beyond what is available for non-hosted content. I'm afraid that you'll need to host your thumbnails on a server under your own control (keying it to the product identifier).

On the plus side, it's probably easier and quicker to update thumbnails on your own server than dealing with iTunes Connect!

Comment: Thanks- If I'm going to do that, I might as well put the data files on my website too, right with the thumbnails.

Comment: I would, although depending on the size of what you're offering you might save some bandwidth and storage costs by letting Apple do it.